# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string Wanna make a db connector with another php page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please help! I am trying to make this db_connect.php file create a config one(that i'll use to connect to db on other pages) after another one has set up the host user and password. and php just won't let me create it. Sorry... I'm begginer. Just wanna learn :3.

```
<?php
    $servername = $_GET["servername"];
    $username = $_GET["user"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $myfile = fopen("../one-config.php", "w");

    $myfile = fopen("../one-config.php", "w") or die("Error 403 file not found.");
    $txt = "<?php
    $servername = ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fwrite($myfile, $servername);
    $txt = "; $username = ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fwrite($myfile, $username);
    $txt = "; password = ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fwrite($myfile, $password);
    $txt = "; ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$conn) {
        die(\"Connection failed:\" . $conn->connect_error());
    }
    echo 'hi!';
    ?>";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);


    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

Comment: Did the error message provide a line number?

Comment: I will guess the issue is on line 29. Once that is fixed then line numbers 34-39 will do something funky but will not produce errors.

Comment: i was so stupid... i forgot to cancel the $conn variable with a backslash before it, twice and a few $servername, $username and $password, so it does not use them as variables and it uses them as normal text to be typed on the next php file. :)) ty for trying to help me, thoe :) (y)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Glad you got it figured out :-)